# Examples of OOP programming with static properties and methods in PHP

Tags: php, oop, static

I am currently a beginner in PHP OOP programming and was wondering if someone could provide an example of how using static properties and methods are useful in real web applications.

Comment: people generally frown upon the use of static properties, as it's a global state, which causes hard to track bugs and makes unit testing difficult. there are exceptions of course.

Comment: There are many uses for `static` class methods. That doesn't mean you'll necessarily use them *all the time* though. Try to learn/follow OO patterns and they'll come up sooner or later. For example, factory patterns use them a lot. Or simply utility functions that a class uses internally, but that you may as well use independently.

Comment: Is there a website you suggest I go to to learn OO/factory patterns

Comment: Singleton pattern: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php But dont start overusing it (the pattern). Also static methods are not OOP, its a disguised procedural programming: http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/

Comment: @Imre That article is rather hyperbolic. Yes, the author has a point, but he's generalizing too much. `static` methods are only problematic for unit testing if they're not idempotent or if they have unseen dependencies. Both are not automatically properties of `static` methods. In the end they're just *functions*, and *purely functional code* is extremely easy to test.

Comment: @ImreL static methods have existed since the very beginning of OOP. If you don't know how and when to use them, then you don't really understand OOP. Static methods *ARE* part of object oriented programming, and without them OOP is almost uselessly crippled. Just because it's similar to something done in another programming pattern  doesn't mean it's not OOP.

Comment: Lately i found using statics in PHP <5.3 pretty cumbersome. I very well know that statics are part of OOP but i dont recommend looking too much into it for those new to PHP. +1 @deceze

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although statics can have problems as pointed out in the comments, they do have a few uses.

One which I've found quite useful is "named constructors".

Typically a class would have a single constructor. But what if the class could be initialized in several different ways?

For example, perhaps your application supports creating users with an email address, or from a Facebook User ID...

```
class User {
    public function __construct($emailOrFbUserId) { } 
}
```

As you can see above, it could be a bit confusing to what the parameter in the constructor was when you use the class.

Instead, by writing it like this...

```
class User {
    private function __construct() { }

    public static function fromEmailAddress($email) {
        $user = new User();

        //assuming there's a private field called email
        $user->email = $email;
        return $user
    }

    public static function fromFacebookUserId($id) {
        ...
    }
}

//usage example
$user = User::fromEmailAddress('foo@bar.com');
```

...and it suddenly makes much more sense.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to extract the methods you call "named constructors" and move them in a UserFactory class?

Comment: Do you know if this is this how websites program their websites to login or signup their users using fb data?

Comment: @DavideGualano interesting idea, but decades of OOP say that factory methods should be static methods in the class that they create. Having a separate class would cause all kinds of problems, for example your factory wouldn't be able to access private or protected properties. Creating subclasses would also get complicated really fast, especially once you have subclasses of subclasses. It goes against the general "complex code is buggy code" theory.

Comment: @JacobPerkins yes, some websites do use this technique for doing that, while other websites use other techniques. There are many different ways to design a website.

Comment: @DavideGualano I tend to advocate simplicity, so I'd say "no". However, if your class was to require more complex constructing logic (say perhaps it would need some other dependencies), then you could consider using a factory class.

Comment: @JacobPerkins Yes, coincidentally this is what I've used in a real solution ;) However as Abhi pointed out it would largely depend on how your specific system requires you to solve it, so you could use other approaches to it as well.

Comment: Abhi and Jani, thanks for your useful and informative comments.